# Perl selenium remote driver cannot create a new instance

Tags: perl, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My perl script couldn't connect to the selenium standalone server running in localhost port 4444. In different environment different things happen.

**Windows 7 :** The script works sometimes and sometimes it doesnt.

Selenium server side : starts properly. but there is no new session created when I create remote driver instance.

```
C:\Users\ganess4\msant\nsn_testeng\tools\AutoBuildPromotionEmail>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar
Dec 3, 2013 12:16:43 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a standalone server
12:16:43.882 INFO - Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 20.14-b01
12:16:43.882 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 x86
12:16:43.894 INFO - v2.37.0, with Core v2.37.0. Built from revision a7c61cb
12:16:43.953 INFO - Default driver org.openqa.selenium.iphone.IPhoneDriver regis
tration is skipped: registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=MAC, brows
erName=iPhone, version=}] does not match with current platform: VISTA
12:16:43.973 INFO - Default driver org.openqa.selenium.iphone.IPhoneDriver regis
tration is skipped: registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=MAC, brows
erName=iPad, version=}] does not match with current platform: VISTA
12:16:44.020 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.
1:4444/wd/hub
12:16:44.021 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
12:16:44.022 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server
/driver]
12:16:44.023 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
12:16:44.024 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
12:16:44.074 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@1754ad
2
12:16:44.074 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
12:16:44.112 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
12:16:44.112 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@c1b531
```

Code Side: Note I did try port 4444 and other variations.

```
my $browser = "firefox";
    my $platform = "WINDOWS";
    eval
    {
        $self->{seldriverarray} = new Selenium::Remote::Driver(browser_name => $browser, platform => $platform);
        $self->{seldriverarray}->debug_on;
        print Dumper $self->{seldriverarray}->status;
    };
```

Throws the following

```
Use of uninitialized value in string ne at C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Selenium/Re
mote/RemoteConnection.pm line 30, <FH> line 48.
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Selenium/Re
mote/RemoteConnection.pm line 35, <FH> line 48.
Selenium server did not return proper status at C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Seleni
um/Remote/Driver.pm line 232.
```

*The weirdest thing happens when I run it in another environment*
**Suse Enterprise Edition:**

Selenium server side: see it creates a new session, which implies that the code is not wrong. So, what is stopping the code to launch a new session in windows? I couldnt run the script in linux, because it is timing out for a long time struggling to launch the firefox.

```
12:32:09.969 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@181edf4
12:32:19.041 INFO - Executing: [new session: {platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, version=}] at URL: /session)
12:32:19.057 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, browserName=firefox, version=}]
```

Comment: if you look at the grid console you will see what capabilities the hub has so from the host you started it on http://localhost:4444/grid/console I suspect you might need something like VISTA for the platform

Comment: I turned on the debug option in the Selenium RemoteConnection.pm code and I saw that it is timing out in LWP http package.

`package LWP::Protocol::http::SocketMethods;  
sub sysread {
    my $self = shift;
    if (my $timeout = ${*$self}{**io_socket_timeout**}) {
 **die "read timeout" unless $self->can_read($timeout)**;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

After updating the Net::HTTPS and the IO::Socket::SSL, this got resolved.