# Perl error "selenium server did not return proper status" when starts PhantomJS

Tags: perl, selenium, phantomjs

I'm using two computers to test a Perl code. On a computer works perfectly, but on the other I get the following error when starting the code:

> Selenium server did not return proper status at (eval 239) line 61

Simplifying the code, the error happens in this simple script:

```
#!usr/bin/env perl

use common::sense;
use WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS;

my $phantom = WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS->new();

__END__
```

Comment: Are you using the same versions of Perl and WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS on both machines? Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357900/perl-selenium-remote-driver-cannot-create-a-new-instance).

Comment: The only difference is that one computer is 32b (with the problem), and the other is 64b (what works). I've seen this question, I tried to update the modules, but has not solved the problem.

Comment: What is in the selenium logs?

Comment: Using the constructor `WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS->new(log => 'DEBUG')` I get `[DEBUG - 2014-10-16T12:45:18.701Z] Config - config.init - {"ip":"127.0.0.1","port":"8910","hub":null,"logFile":null,"logLevel":"DEBUG","logColor":false}
[INFO  - 2014-10-16T12:45:18.889Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 8910`. These are the logs you ask?

Comment: Can you see the remote server? `curl other.server.ip:4444/wd/hub/status`...

Answer (score 0):

We had an issue with phantomjs defaulting to SSLv3. When we patched our servers, integration tests started to fail. Workaround by passing `--ssl-protocol=any` to tell phantomjs to use whatever the server prefers.

Comment: I changed the constructor to `WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS->new(phantomjs_arg => ['--ssl-protocol=any'])` and `WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS->new(phantomjs_arg => ['--ssl-protocol=any'], ignore_ssl_errors => 1)`, but not solved